# Is there an application that could predict what I type and auto-complete my words and sentences?

Tags: keyboard, autocomplete, productivity

I use to type a lot of text (in the browser) repeating the same stuff, using the same words and even same sentences over and over again. It would save me a lot of time if the computer could guess what I am going to type and suggest autocompletion options. Is there a way to get this functionality in Linux (XUbuntu)?

Comment: LibreOffice Writer will suggest word completion.

Comment: ... sysadmins who shopped for `rm` also shopped for `-rf` ...

Comment: did you mean `yum *remove* java` ?

Comment: You might be better off doing it in an editor, and then copying it to the browser. And editors are relatively good at (customizable) autocompleting.

Comment: @FaheemMitha what editor has got the best autocompletion ("out of the box" or almost, I know EMACS can do everything but you are to spend serious time configuring it first, AFAIK) then? Not for coding but for writing letters to humans?

Comment: Notepad++ (alas on Windows) makes suggestions when you are coding simple things. There was a mention of bringing it to Linux but dunno what the state of that effort is right now. Maybe you can run it under WINE if you are desperate to have this functionality.

Comment: @Ivan Well, I'd suggest Emacs, because that's what I use. And I don't know if it really requires so much configuration.I've not looked into it. You could ask at https://emacs.stackexchange.com. Do a search first, of course. See e.g. https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9920/auto-complete-mode-inside-predictive-mode-org-mode